# Como Listar Archivos en PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

tengo 2 funciones que me listan los archivos de una carpeta y subcarpetas para retornar el directorio del archivo y su nombre en un array para después insertarlos en una datatable a través de un json pero de 32 archivos solo me esta regresando 27 (T_T), tengo ya un día entero con esto y no da mi cabeza para más.

```
public function listadoDirectorio()
{
    $datos = $this->input->post();
    $id_seguimiento = $datos['id_seguimiento'];
    $id_cliente = $datos['id_cliente'];
    $directorio = FCPATH . 'assets/uploads/ctes' . '/' . $id_cliente . '/seguimiento' . '/' . $id_seguimiento;
    $dir = opendir($directorio);
    $files = array();
    $archivos = array();
    while (false !== ($current = readdir($dir))) {
        $ruta_completa = $directorio . "/" . $current;
        if ($current !== "." && $current !== "..") {
            if (is_dir($ruta_completa)) {
                $subarchivos = $this->listadoSubDirectorio($ruta_completa . '/',  $archivos);
                $archivos = array_merge($archivos, $subarchivos);
            } else {
                $files[] = $current;
            }
        }
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
        $archivos[$i]["directorio"] = $directorio;
        $archivos[$i]['nombre'] = $files[$i];
    }
    closedir($dir);
    echo json_encode($archivos);
}
public function listadoSubDirectorio($directorio, $archivos)
{
    $dir = opendir($directorio);
    $files = array();
    $subarchivos = array();
    $subarchivos2 = array();
    while (false !== ($current = readdir($dir))) {
        $ruta_completa = $directorio . "/" . $current;
        if ($current !== "." && $current !== "..") {
            if (is_dir($ruta_completa)) {
                $subarchivos2 = $this->listadoSubDirectorio($ruta_completa . '/',  $archivos);
                $subarchivos = array_merge($subarchivos, $subarchivos2);
            } else {
                $files[] = $current;
            }
        }
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
        $subarchivos[$i]["directorio"] = $directorio;
        $subarchivos[$i]['nombre'] = $files[$i];
    }
    closedir($dir);
    return $subarchivos;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Opción 1

Prueba con lo siguiente

```
function getDirFiles($dirName) {
    $result = [];
    if (file_exists($dirName)) {
        $d = scandir($dirName);
        foreach($d as $file) {
            if (is_dir("$dirName/$file") && $file !== "." && $file !== "..") {
                array_push($result, getDirFiles("$dirName/$file"));
            } else {
                if ($file !== "." && $file !== "..") {
                    array_push($result, "$file");
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    } else {
        return "Directorio no existe";
  `  }
}
```

Este código escaneará un directorio dinámicamente, si existen subdirectorios te retornará los archivos de ese subdirectorio en un array dentro del array retornado.

### Opción 2

```
function getDirFiles($dirName) {
    $result = [];
    if (file_exists($dirName)) {
        $d = scandir($dirName);
        foreach($d as $file) {
            if (is_dir("$dirName/$file") && $file !== "." && $file !== "..") {
               $b = scandir("$dirName/$file");
               foreach($b as $f2) {
                   if (is_file("$dirName/$file/$f2")) {
                       array_push($result, "$dirName/$file/$f2");
                   }
               }
            } else {
                if ($file !== "." && $file !== "..") {
                    array_push($result, "$file");
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    } else {
        return "Directorio no existe";
    }
}
```

Esto escaneará el directorio, en caso de subdirectorios, retornará los elementos en el mismo array con "nombreDir/subdir/archivo", solo funciona con archivos dentro de los subdirectorios, no funcionará con directorios dentro de los subdirectorios.

### Opción 3

```
function getDirFiles($dirName) {
    $result = [];
    if (file_exists($dirName)) {
        $d = scandir($dirName);
        foreach($d as $file) {
            if (is_dir("$dirName/$file") && $file !== "." && $file !== "..") {
               $b = scandir("$dirName/$file");
               foreach($b as $f2) {
                   if (is_file("$dirName/$file/$f2")) {
                       array_push($result, "$dirName/$file/$f2");
                   } elseif (is_dir("$dirName/$file/$f2")) {
                       if ($f2 !== "." && $f2 !== "..") {
                           $f3 = getDirFiles("$dirName/$file/$f2");
                           foreach($f3 as $f4) {
                            array_push($result, "$dirName/$file/$f2/$f4");
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
            } else {
                if ($file !== "." && $file !== "..") {
                    array_push($result, "$file");
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    } else {
        return "Directorio no existe";
    }
}
```

Esto escaneará el directorio, en caso de directorios dentro de los subdirectorios del directorio principal, añadirá un elemento al array que retorna: "dirPrincipal/subdir/subdir2/archivo", esto hará lo mismo si hay más subdirectorios dentro de otros subdirectorios y sucesivamente.

Comment: lo resolví (enseguida pongo lo que hice ) pero muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

Al final pude resolverlo, estaba sobrescribiendo mi array de salida por eso omitía algunos archivos.
Aqui dejo la solución

```
public function listadoDirectorio()
{
    $datos = $this->input->post();
    $id_seguimiento = $datos['id_seguimiento'];
    $id_cliente = $datos['id_cliente'];
    $directorio = FCPATH . 'assets/uploads/ctes' . '/' . $id_cliente . '/seguimiento' . '/' . $id_seguimiento;
    $dir = opendir($directorio);
    $files = array();
    $archivos = array();
    while (false !== ($current = readdir($dir))) {
        $ruta_completa = $directorio . "/" . $current;
        if ($current !== "." && $current !== "..") {
            if (is_dir($ruta_completa)) {
                $subarchivos = $this->listadoSubDirectorio($ruta_completa . '/',  $archivos);
                $archivos = array_merge($archivos, $subarchivos);
            } else {
                $files[] = $current;
            }
        }
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
        $subarchivos2[$i] = [
            'directorio' => $directorio,
            'nombre' => $files[$i]
        ];
    }
    $archivos = array_merge($subarchivos2, $archivos);
    closedir($dir);
    echo json_encode($archivos);
}
public function listadoSubDirectorio($directorio, $archivos)
{
    $dir = opendir($directorio);
    $files = array();
    $subarchivos = array();
    $subarchivos2 = array();
    while (false !== ($current = readdir($dir))) {
        $ruta_completa = $directorio . "/" . $current;
        if ($current !== "." && $current !== "..") {
            if (is_dir($ruta_completa)) {
                $subarchivos2 = $this->listadoSubDirectorio($ruta_completa . '/',  $archivos);
                $subarchivos = array_merge($subarchivos, $subarchivos2);
            } else {
                $files[] = $current;
            }
        }
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
        $subarchivos[$i] = [
            'directorio' => $directorio,
            'nombre' => $files[$i]
        ];
    }
    closedir($dir);
    return $subarchivos;
}
```